# setting google map from and to direction from input fields

Tags: javascript, html

I have two fields a from and to and I just simply want to display the from and to on the map upon submitting.

I am having trouble figuring out the `origin` and `destination` options for the map.

**HTML:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        function myMap() {
            var mapOptions = {
                origin: new google.maps.LatLng(59.426862, 24.743414),
                destination: new google.maps.LatLng(59.438337, 24.756494),
                zoom: 10,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
            }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDFOR-jYbVDU9ariN9UWKhldnV8M_nbrjQ&callback=myMap"></script>

    <div id="input-container">
        <input type="text" name="from" placeholder="From" class="special">
        <input type="text" name="from" placeholder="To">
        <input type="submit">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hope this help http://jsfiddle.net/zufnmkgg/

Comment: @TanDuong i managed to get a version working in fiddle, but in a seprate file I need to define google to it, where should that go?

Comment: never mind, figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// change form code like this 

<form>
 <div id="input-container">
        <input type="text" name="from" placeholder="From" class="special">
        <input type="text" name="to" placeholder="To">
        <input type="submit" >
 </div>
 </form>

// using jquery update your map
<script>
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  from = $( "input[name='from']" ).val();
  to   = $( "input[name='to']" ).val();

  var myOptions = {
                    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(form),
                    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(to),
                    zoom: 10,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
                };
    map.set(myOptions);
  event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```